# How does an eraser erase pencil writings?

Tags: everyday-life, material-science

We can erase our pencil writings by an eraser but we can't by our hand for example.. so what does happen at the microscopic level and how the eraser just do its job?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about physics. It might be possible to make it on topic by identifying the physics concept at the core of the question and narrowing it down to that.

Comment: I disagree on this question being closed as off-topic with the reason "not-about-physics". This is a question of the type "how does the physics of this effect/phenomenon/situation work". Voting to re-open.

Comment: @Steeven IMO, that style of question asked ought be closed as too broad because there isn't a single specific concept being asked but a generalization of an event.